# Затруднение в нахождении наименьшего среди средних арифметических значений

Tags: c++

Вообщем проблема в следующем.

Дано задание:

Результаты сессии, состоящей из четырех экзаменов, для трех групп из 25 студентов представлены трехмерным массивом 3х25х4. Оценка ставится по четырехбалльной системе; неявка обозначена единицей. Определить, экзамен по какой дисциплине вызвал наибольшие трудности, то есть по какой дисциплине средний балл наименьший.

Большую часть я выполнил, но все же не могу понять, как найти наименьшее среди четырех средних арифметических и как потом вывести на экран именно тот экзамен, где среднее арифметическое наименьшее.

Код прилагаю:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int exams, group, strength, N;
    exams = 4;
    group = 3;
    strength = 2;

    cout << "Введите значение массива: \n";
    int*** arr = new int** [exams];
    for (int i = 0; i < exams; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int*[group];
    }
    ////////////////////////////////

    for (int i = 0; i < exams; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int* [group];

        for (int j = 0; j < group; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = new int[strength];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < exams; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < group; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < strength; k++)
            {
                cin >> arr[i][j][k];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < exams; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < group; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < strength; k++)
            {
                cout << " " << arr[i][j][k] << "\t";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    double* b = new double[exams];
    for (int i = 0; i < exams; i++)
    {
        b[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < exams; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < group; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < strength; k++)
            {
                b[i] += arr[i][j][k];
            }
        }
        int res = group * strength;
        cout << "Средний балл на этом экзамене: " << b[i] / res << endl; 
    }
    ////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < strength; i++)
    {
        delete arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что есть `strength` - ??

Comment: У вас есть конкретные размеры. Зачем вы выделяете память в куче?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan человек видимо из джавы в с++ пришел, знакомая ситуация

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Я бы не стал выделять память для массива в куче, поскольку известны
  все размеры, и обращение к памяти в стеке быстрее.
- Нужно еще учесть, что никто не станет (во всяком случаи не захочет)
  ввести `300 чисел` для заполнения массива, поэтому лучше просто
  инициализировать случайными числами.
- Нужно еще и выполнять все условия задачи, т. е., наприер, не считать
  элементы со значением `1` как оценку, потому что это означает неявка
- Когда выводим на экран, нужно стараться выводить что то осмысленное

Учитывая все это, можно написать например такой код:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");   
const int exams = 4, group = 3, grades = 25;
//названия дисциплин
const char* Exams[exams] = { "math", "phys", "progr", "last" };
//добавим еще один элемент в массив, для хранения суммы 
int arr[group][exams][grades + 1],
    index = 0;
//обьект, хранящую минимальный средый бал,
//инициализирум большим числом
double sum = 0,  min = 1000;    

for (int i = 0; i < group; ++i)
{
    cout <<'\n' << i + 1 << " _ая группа\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < exams; ++j)
    {   
        cout << Exams[j] << ": ";
        for (int k = 0; k < grades; ++k)
        {               
            int m = rand() % 4 + 1;
            arr[i][j][k] = m;               
            cout  << m << "  ";
            //единицей обозначены неявки
            //их не считаем
            if(m > 1)
               sum += m;
        }
        arr[i][j][grades] = sum;
        cout << sum << endl;
        sum = 0;            
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
}

//теперь для каждой группы имеем сумму балов для каждого экзамена
//и нам осталось лишь считать среднее значение для всех груп
//и определить минимальное значение среди них
//и, дополнительно, определим название дисциплины
for (int j = 0; j < exams; ++j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < group; ++i) {
        sum += arr[i][j][grades];
    }
    sum /= int(grades * group);
    if (min > sum) {
        min = sum;
        index = j;
    }
    sum = 0;
}     

cout << "Наибольшая трудность вызвал экзамен по: "
     << Exams[index] << endl << "Средный бал экзамена: " << min;
```

P.S. На наличие ошибок в логике программы, я не проверял, можете сами тестировать и сопровождать

Comment: Выделение памяти в стеке быстрее, чем из кучи, это верно, а вот время доступа к ней одинаково.

Comment: @avp,   https://tproger.ru/translations/programming-concepts-stack-and-heap/

Comment: Не слишком доверяйте всему, что читаете в интернете. Похоже, автор плохо представляет, как работает cache prefetcher

Comment: @avp,  я про это читал в какой то книге еще  давно, а в интернете я нашел после вашего коммента. А разве в кещ память не встраиваются при частом обращении?.. Так как  программирование не моя профессия, а хобби, я может на этот вопрос  выделил не очень большое внимание, поэтому не  стану ничего твердить, но  по  логике  обращаться к разным участкам памяти должно быть медленне, чем в пределах одного стека.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в тех программах, о которых обычно мы тут говорим, **все** обращения к памяти являются обращениями к кэшу. При первой же записи или первом чтении, часть памяти, содержащая данные по запрашиваемому адресу (ее называют cache line, типично 64 байта) перемещается из DDR в кэш (если ее там еще не было). Далее все модификации проходят в кэше. При этом CPU никак не различает память занятую кучей, стеком, bss или другими данными. Время доступа будет различаться только к тем данным, которые уже находятся в кэше от доступа к тем, которых в кэше еще нет.

Comment: В какой-то момент окажется, что места в кэше для новой cache line больше нет, тогда кэш вытолкнет в DDR какую-то cache line (вот так обычно обновляется DDR) и поместит в нее вновь запрошенные данные. В процессе обмена между кэшем и DDR участвует также специальный блок, называемый prefetcher, который на основании статистики обращений к кэшу пытается предсказать, к какому адресу будет обращение в ближайшем будущем и опережающим образом вычитывает одну или несколько cache lines (реально запросам к ним еще не было) из DDR.

Comment: Эта тактика реально хорошо работает при последовательном доступе к элементам массива, повышая на практике производительность в 2-3 раза, по сравнению с отключенным prefetcher (ага, прикладным программистам, работающим под управлением  ОС это не доступно)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Я только не совсем понял, зачем вы min задали значение 1000?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, А для чего? Не, я вижу, что оно дальше используется в if...else, просто не могу понять, для чего нужно это действие.

Comment: Я уже забыл про эту задачу, поэтому неправильно ответил. Я взял такое число, что точно больше среднего балла данного экзамена. Таким образом в первом же цикле min обязательно будет принимать значение  sum ( среднего балла  .первого экзамена) , чтобы потом сравнивать с другими средными значениями

Answer (score 2):

```
double minB = 0;
int minI = 0;
    ...
    b[i] = b[i] / (group * strength);
    if (i == 0 || b[i] < minB) {
      minI = i;
      minB = b[i];
    }
    cout << "Средний балл на этом экзамене: " << b[i] << endl;
    ...
cout << "Lowest балл " << minB << " на экзамене " << minI << endl;
```